# PHP MSSQL - sqlsrv stored procedure no error and no response

Tags: php, sql-server

I created a microsoft sql stored procedure, and I am calling it from the php code below. I do not get any errors, but I do not get any output either. I have looked all over, but I am still fuzzy about how to do the WHILE statement to retrieve the variables I need from sql... I am hoping someone can take a look at the php code below (and the sql code below that) to see what I might be missing. Oh, and when I execute the stored procedure through SQL, it works fine and returns the data I expect. Thanks!

```
    <?php

$serverName = "PRATHIBA-PC\SQL2008";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TMS", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"asset12345" );
//$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TMS");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Could not connect.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}



/* Define the Transact-SQL query. Use question marks (?) in
 place of  the parameters to be passed to the stored procedure 
 */  

$tsql_callSP = "{call Getstudentname( 1 )}";   

$studentid = '1';



$params = array( 
                 array($studentid, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
               );

/* Execute the query. */  
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);   

if( $stmt3 === false ) {       
echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";       
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); }   

/* Display the value of the output parameters. */   
while (sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt3)) {       
// SET PARAMETERS - SET TERMS      
//echo $term;  
}   

/*Free the statement and connection resources. */  


while ($obj=sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt3)) {       
// SET PARAMETERS - SET TERMS      
echo $obj->term;}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt3); 
?>
```

This is SQL Server stored procedure code

```
USE [TMS]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Getstudentname]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

When I run this code I am getting output:

```
exec Getstudentname 1;
```

this is my output in sql server

1   Vivek   Johari  vivek@abc.com

Please help me guys..

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a question mark as a place-holder for the parameter like this:

```
$tsql_callSP = "{call Getstudentname(?)}";
```

Not sure if this will help?